# show text only on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

i have problem with hover,i want text and span to shows only on hover,but in my case text and span is show all the time,i think font is hard to read any advice to fix it ? Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/5xqs7cp1/1/

```
<li class="one"><img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZy3vOp.jpg" alt="" />
<h2>some text</h2>
      <span class="h1"></span>
      <span class="h2"></span>
      <span class="h3"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: It is not clear in the fiddle how you are trying to hide the elements when not hovering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, then you can try to add to `.grid li` class this:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

---

Also, if you want your text to appear with some easing, then just add to `.grid li h2` class this line:

```
opacity: 0;
```

And to this class `.grid li:hover h2`:

```
opacity: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
span,
h2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

span:hover,
h2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```